# Firebase Job Dispatcher doesn't trigger the service class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-job-dispatcher

I created static methods on an activity to call the jobscheduler
Jobdispatcher doesn't dispatch the job, I guess. Please help.

The methods in class Add.java

```
public void add_details(String namel,String descl,String timel)
{
    add_job(timel);

}
synchronized public void add_job(String time)
{     
    Driver driver = new GooglePlayDriver(Add.this);
    FirebaseJobDispatcher firebaseJobDispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(driver);
    Job job = firebaseJobDispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(Addition_job.class)
                .setTag(JOB_TAG)
                .setRecurring(true)
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(5,30))
                .build();
    firebaseJobDispatcher.mustSchedule(job);
}
```

Addition_job.class

```
public class Addition_job extends JobService{
private AsyncTask Task;
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) {
    Task=new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            Context context=Addition_job.this;
            Decision.notify_user(context);
            return null;
        }
    };
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
    if (Task != null) Task.cancel(true);
    return true;
}
}
```

Decision.java
notifiy_user method

```
public static void notify_user(Context context)
{
    if(context!=null)
        Toast.makeText(context,"notified:",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I have specified the service in the manifest with `export=false` and also `action_Execute`.

Comment: You do not call `AsyncTask.execute()`. You also need to call `jobFinished` when your `AsyncTask` is finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have very rigid constrain (i.e starting job exactly after some minutes or seconds) then maybe it is good idea to implement this with AlarmManager because there is no guarantee with JobDispatcher, that your task will work at the time specified, it might start to work in a few hours later.
 
On API 21+ Doze mode will also come into factor in deciding the time at which your task will execute.
If you want really strict scheduling - use AlarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle.

Comment: Where is info about 'a few hours later' from? https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/issues/83 this says about 50ms to minute.